# A thread is still trying to access a disposed form?

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a thread that downloads and reports the download status to a progress bar and a label. It always crashes when trying to invoke a object in a disposed form (Progress bar & label) even when there's a `if (!this.Disposed)` is called before, and still throws the exception even with a `catch (ObjectDisposedException)` is called in the same try block. I'm not sure what I can do to fix this, it's probably best described as the most annoying thing I've ever encountered.

Thanks you.

---

Update (from a considerate SO lurker) of my source found on pastebin

```
Thread downloader();
public bool abortThread = false();

private void frmDownload_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    downloader.Abort(); // Abort the thread before closing the form...?
    abortThread = true; // Set the abortThread to true
    this.Dispose(); // Dispose thread
}

downloader = new Thread(() => {
    string[] URLs = { "http://test1.com/", "http://test2.com/", "http://test3.com/" };
    try {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => {
                if (!pbDownloadStatus.IsDisposed && !lbPercentage.IsDisposed) {
                    if (!abortThread) {
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pbDownloadStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage)); // EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pbDownloadStatus.Value++));
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pbDownloadStatus.Value--));
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbPercentage.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%"));
                        }
                    }
                };
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => {
                    if (!pbDownloadStatus.IsDisposed && !lbPercentage.IsDisposed) {
                        lock (e.UserState) {
                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => pbDownloadStatus.Value = 0));
                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbPercentage.Text = "0%"));
                            Monitor.Pulse(e.UserState);
                        }
                    }
                };
                wc.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
                wc.Headers.Add(header);
                for (int i = 0; i < URLs.Length; i++) {
                    var sync = new Object();
                    lock (sync) {
                        wc.DownloadFileAsycn(new Uri(URLs[i]), "C:\Test\URL" + i);
                        Monitor.Wait(sync);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException disEx) { // Never gets caught
        downloader.Abort();
        MessageBox.Show("Object was disposed");
    }
});
downloader.Start();
```

Comment: Can you show us some more code? Does the debugger hit your if statement and if so can you tell us why it gets passed it? Is this an event on a background worker thread being called? If so should you actually be removing the event when your form is being disposed?

Comment: It's possible for an object to not be disposed when your if statement executes, but get disposed before your next line executes (when dealing with multiple threads).

Comment: I don't know how I can put the code in a comment, so I put it on pastebin -> https://pastebin.com/xFaheF3m

Comment: This code has more issues than the Titanic, However since we can see it now, im sure you'll get a suitable answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/)

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, multithreaded programming is
>   greatly simplified with the System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel and
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task classes, Parallel LINQ (PLINQ), new
>   concurrent collection classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent
>   namespace, and a new programming model that is based on the concept of
>   tasks rather than threads

The need to work with threads directly in the modern era is greatly reduced, and you should probably look at `Tasks` and `async/await` Tasks can be cancelled, are easier to manage and async returns back to the calling context.

Secondly, your code doesn't make sense, and its full of compiler errors which is not a good start for a question. Additionally, since there is so much wrong with the code i have decided to just give you lots of points to think about apposed to rewriting it all

So lets look at some of the more obvious issues this code has.

1. `abortThread` is accessed from multiple threads and is not thread safe for the most part.
2. You are calling `var sync = new Object();` directly before `lock (sync)` meaning you are locking nothing
3. Even if that lock statement was going to work, there is no other thread using the lock, meaning its redundant.
4. You are calling `this.Dispose()` from the forms closing event. This is unusal to say the least

   - > The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it
     >   is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the
     >   form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using
     >   ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to
     >   mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.
   - Basically in a non MDI application, If you call `ShowDialog` then put it in a using statement.
5. You are trying to check `IsDisposed` to determine if its safe to marshal back to the UI thread.

   - Just because you call `Dispose` doesn't mean the form IS disposed, this is not how it works and will not solve your problem.
6. If you need to do asynchronous IO bound work, Use the `aysnc`,`await` pattern, then you wont be blocking a thread for spurious reasons waiting for a completion port. If you need to run this in parallel, then consider DataFlow with action blocks so you can take advantage of `aysnc`,`await` and parallel.
7. If you need to determine whether a form is alive or dead, use a thread safe variable. Use a static Lock object, and every where you update the variable use lock as well.
8. if you need to marshal to the UI thread. Don't do `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()` multiple times, Do it once, and update everything at once.

Comment: Sorry for taking a bit, something important came up. But, it's just snippets of the main code, I only post snippets because I'd need to remove a ton of revealing information from the main code. Anyway, I use threads so I can update the form while it downloads. It basically pops open a form and downloads something. I was also reconsidering recoding it from scratch because it does kinda go off in a wrong direction. Thanks for the information, I will look more into everything.